# causes why the images are not loaded on site but in firebug

Tags: html, firefox, firebug

![the screenshot shows that images are not displayed on browser even in firebug the path of the images are not loaded successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8ja3.png)[1the screenshot shows that images are not displayed on browser even in firebug the path of the images are not loaded successfully]I tried to display a list of images on browser.But the images are not loaded.When i checked through firebug,all images are loaded properly.but the images are not displayed on browser.I faced this problem  on Firefox browser.when i did check in chrome and safari it didn't display anything .

Comment: Code. Screenshot. Url. Anything...

Comment: Not giving any width or height to div with image as background?

Comment: Obviously your screenshot wasn't included correctly. @jszobody the link to it works, though.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox doesn't display local images on remote resources due to [security reasons](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_do_not_work).

Firebug doesn't have these restrictions. So that's why you see the preview of your image there.

Sebastian